# limit of characteristic function and relation of primitive

Tags: distribution-theory

1. If I have $h(x)=1_A(x) \, f(x) = \begin{cases}f(x) & \text{if } x \in A \\ 0 & \text{if } x \not\in A\end{cases}$,
   where $A$ is an arbitrary set,
   then why it's equal to $f(x)$ almost everywhere?
2. Is there equality between an infinity norm of a function and its primitive?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. It isn't in general. For example, with $f(x)\equiv 1$ and $A=\emptyset$ we have $1_A(x) \, f(x) \equiv 0 \neq f(x) \equiv 1$ everywhere.
2. No, there isn't. For example, $f_n(x) = \sin nx$ where $n=1,2,3,\ldots$ all have $\|f_n\| = 1$ but $\|f_n'\|=n$. Thus there is no such equality.

Comment: if A non-empty, is it true?

Comment: No, take $A=\{0\}$ in my example. You will then have $1_A(x) \, f(x) = 0$ for all $x \neq 0$, and $1_A(x) \, f(x) = f(x) = 1$ only for $x=0$. That's still far from "almost everywhere".